# Calculating mean of level based on the status

Tags: r

Calculating the mean  my data looks like this

```
    -----------
    level   sts
    -----------
    10      s
    -----------
    11      s
    -----------
    10      s
    -----------
    10      s
    -----------
    10      s
    -----------
    9       r
    -----------
    8.5     r
    -----------
    8       s
    -----------
    8.1     s
    -----------
    8       s
    -----------
```

calculate mean based on sts(s = stop, r = running). I want to output to be like this

```
    -----------
    level   sts
    -----------
    10.2     s
    -----------
    9        r
    -----------
    8.5      r
    -----------
    8.03     s
    -----------
```

finally, the output will look like this

```
    -----------
    level   sts
    -----------
    10.2    s
    -----------
    10.2    s
    -----------
    10.2    s
    -----------
    10.2    s
    -----------
    10.2    s
    -----------
    9       r
    -----------
    8.5     r
    -----------
    8.03    s
    -----------
    8.03    s
    -----------
    8.03    s
    ---------
```

If answer is already available please provide me the link thank you

Comment: Add another indicator variable and then use your favorite aggregation function.

Comment: You can use `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, .(level = mean(level)),.(sts, grp = rleid(sts))]`

Comment: Why isn't `sts == "r"` aggregated? Is there a rule behind that behavior?

Comment: Yes, when the vehicle is idle the device is giving information like above so thinking of to replacing level with mean when the sts is 's'. and when the vehicle is running the fuel level will decrease.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your desired output, I'd try something like:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, group := rleid(sts)][
  sts == "s", level := mean(level), .(sts, group)][]
#         level sts group
#  1: 10.200000   s     1
#  2: 10.200000   s     1
#  3: 10.200000   s     1
#  4: 10.200000   s     1
#  5: 10.200000   s     1
#  6:  9.000000   r     2
#  7:  8.500000   r     2
#  8:  8.033333   s     3
#  9:  8.033333   s     3
# 10:  8.033333   s     3
```

I suppose with the "tidyverse", the equivalent should be something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table) # for `rleid`

mydf %>%
  mutate(group = rleid(sts)) %>%
  group_by(sts, group) %>%
  mutate(level = case_when(
    sts == "s" ~ mean(level),
    TRUE ~ level
  ))
```

---

Sample data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(level = c(10, 11, 10, 10, 10, 9, 8.5, 8, 8.1, 
    8), sts = c("s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "r", "r", "s", "s", "s")),
    .Names = c("level", "sts"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```